# Регулярные выражения в javascript

Tags: javascript

Я получаю ajax'ом такую строку:

```
<option value='0'>Центральный район</option>
<option value='1'>Невский район</option>
<option value='2'>Адмиралтейский район</option>
<option value='3'>Василеостровский район</option>
```

Всё это находится в переменной data, и мне нужно спарсить все названия (например: Пушкинский район, и.т.д.) в массив var option = ['Пушкинский район',['и.т.д.']]

Помогите пожалуйста построить регулярку.

Comment: Почему не используешь JSON в таком случае?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как.
Там всё генерируется так:

$ray = explode("\n",$rayon['data']['initial']);
for($i=0;$i<18;$i++){
echo("<option value='{$i}'>{$ray[$i]}</option>\r\n");
}

Как это превратить в JSON не знаю, а даже если знаю, будет больше мороки с javascript, а мне проще на PHP всё делать.

Comment: Ужас ужасный... Морока на js - это как раз строить regexp и обрабатывать массив по второму разу на клиенте. Сейчас отпишу ответ

Comment: AJAX-запрос делается через jQuery?

Comment: ДА! Через jQuery!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"success": function(resp) {
    window.list = [];
    $('<select>').html(resp).find('option').each(function(){
        // Если массив обрабатывается 1 раз, то это можно сделать тут же, без создания переменной
        window.list.push($(this).text());})
    });
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Буду разбираться дальше.

Answer (score 0):

```
var res, result=[],str, reg;
str ="<option value='0'>Центральный район</option><option value='1'>Невский район</option><option value='2'>Адмиралтейский район</option><option value='3'>Василеостровский район</option>";
reg = />([^<>]+)</g;
while ( (res = reg.exec(str)) != null) {
  result.push(res[1]);
}
```

// result содержит нужный массив

Answer (score 0):

Глупо тра*аться с JS кодом, если использовать JSON + изменить PHP код, удобнее

```
$ray = explode("\n",$rayon['data']['initial']);
$result = array();
for($i=0;$i<18;$i++){
$result[$i] = $ray[$i]; 
}
return $result;

А вот что должно быть в JS ->
(не видел ваш код, поэтому покажу пример с POST запросом )
$.post("обработчик.php",
{данные которые передаете},
function(data){
   for(var i=0;i<18;i++)
   {
   alert(data[i]);
   }
},
"json");
```